# RegExp works with String.match, but does not work with String.split

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, match

I have a CSV file type I need to parse.  The below is exactly the conditions I need to account for (missing column titles, line breaks within quotes, missing data etc):

```
ID,NAME,TITLE,DESCRIPTION,,
PRO1234,"JOHN SMITH",ENGINEER,"JOHN HAS BEEN WORKING

HARD ON BEING A GOOD

SERVENT."
PRO1235,"KEITH SMITH",ENGINEER,"keith has been working

hard on being a good

servent."
PRO1235,"KENNY SMITH",,"keith has been working

hard on being a good

servent."
PRO1235,"RICK SMITH",,,
```

You'll notice that there are line feeds within the description as well as line feeds for new rows of data.

I've written this regular expression to find the line feeds OUTSIDE of quotes, and it works great [**here**](http://regex101.com/r/mL0dG7/3)

Code, using Node.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function parseCSV(filename){
    var rx = new RegExp(/\n(?=([^"\\]*(\\.|"([^"\\]*\\.)*[^"\\]*"))*[^"]*$)/g);
    var strFile = fs.readFileSync(filename).toString();
    console.log("line feed count via match: " + strFile.match(rx).length);
    var csv = strFile.split(rx);

    console.log("csv length: " + csv.length);
    console.log("csv items ###############################");
    csv.forEach(function(e,i,a){
        console.log("item e: " + e);
    });
}
```

When I run this, you'll see that the line feed count (line returns found by match) is correct, which is **4**.  However, when using same ret with String.split(), it's comes back with **17** and the resulting array is erratic:

```
line feed count via match: 4
csv length: 17
csv items ###############################
item e: ID,NAME,TITLE,DESCRIPTION,,
item e: 
PRO1235,"RICK SMITH"
item e: "RICK SMITH"
item e: undefined
item e: PRO1234,"JOHN SMITH",ENGINEER,"JOHN HAS BEEN WORKING

HARD ON BEING A GOOD

SERVENT."
item e: 
PRO1235,"RICK SMITH"
item e: "RICK SMITH"
item e: undefined
item e: PRO1235,"KEITH SMITH",ENGINEER,"keith has been working

hard on being a good

servent."
item e: 
PRO1235,"RICK SMITH"
item e: "RICK SMITH"
item e: undefined
item e: PRO1235,"KENNY SMITH",,"keith has been working

hard on being a good

servent."
item e: PRO1235,"RICK SMITH"
item e: "RICK SMITH"
item e: undefined
item e: PRO1235,"RICK SMITH",,,
```

What am I doing wrong with split?  My thought is that if I can identify 4 linebreaks that works perfectly with match(), then that same regEx should provide the locations of where to "split" the string up.

Comment: Classic case of reinventing the wheel. [Why not use a dedicated CSV parser for this?](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/)

Comment: First off you can't parse strings starting from the middle of them.

Comment: sln - can you explain your comment a bit more?  How was I parsing a string in the middle if I'm calling string.split(regExp)?

Comment: Are you trying to parse the csv file ? If so, this regex will handle it with/without your newline problem. `/(?:(?:^|,|\r?\n)\s*)(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*)"(?:\s*(?:(?=,|\r?\n)|$))|([^,]*)(?:\s*(?:(?=,)|$)))/` The field value is `$1$2`

Answer (score 1):

You have too many capture groups. Split will return the captured groups when it splits the string.
Consider the following simple example:

```
var simpleString = "111aaa222bbb";
var regxNoCaptureGroup = /\d+/;
var regxWithCaptureGroup = /(\d+)/;
var regxWithNoncapturingGroup = /(?:\d+)/;

simpleString.split(regxNoCaptureGroup); //["", "aaa", "bbb"]
simpleString.split(regxWithNoncapturingGroup); //same as above
simpleString.split(regxWithCaptureGroup); //["", "111", "aaa", "222", "bbb"]  - includes captured groups
```

You have capture groups within capture groups. Keep in mind that split will find the group, and remove it to find the split part, so splitting around numbers (as in the first example) will return only the letters. 
In your case, it will remove whatever is captured.
With capture groups, it will return them in the result - so if you plan on using split with a regex, you should probably build a good regex which only captures what is needed.

Comment: Thanks Etai, I'll take a look at my regExp - I appreciate your explanation and time - it does make sense.

Comment: np. Since it answers your question regarding split vs match, please feel free to mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to anubhava for their answer, which worked just fine:

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
var csv = require('./jquery.csv-0.71.min.js');
var fs = require('fs');

var strFile = fs.readFileSync("./data/TestData.csv").toString();
var obj = $.csv.toObjects(strFile);
var str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);

console.log("str: " + str);
```

Who doesn't like a new set of wheels?

In my defense, I'd tried 3 tools on node and all 3 were written for the most simple of situations and files in pristine condition.